# Region of convergence of the power series $\sum \frac{1}{n} z^{n}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find Region of convergence of the power series $\sum \frac{1}{n}z^{n}$. It is clear that it's radius of convergence is equal to $1$ and its circle  of convergence is given by $|z|<1$. I am trying to find its complete region of convergence . Now by p- test it divergent at $1$ but in my book it is given that it is convergent at all others point of circle of convergence. At $-1$ it is convergent by Leibniz test. Please suggest me how to check at all other events points. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: it is the classical series expansion of $\log(1-z)$ ... then...

Comment: But it's series is in alternate form

Comment: But I want a solution without using thae fact of analytic function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|z|=1$, then we can describe $z$ parametrically as $z=e^{i\phi}$ with $0\le \phi<2\pi$.  Then, note that

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{in\phi}\right|=\left|\frac{\sin(N\phi/2)}{\sin(\phi/2)}\right|\le \csc(\phi/2)$$

Hence, for any fixed $\phi \in (0,2\pi)$, the sum $\left|\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{in\phi}\right|$ is bounded.

Inasmuch as $\frac1n$ approaches zero monotonically, [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Statement) guarantees that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{in\phi}}{n}$ converges for $\phi\in (0,2\pi)$.

> Finally, we conclude that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ converges for all $z\ne 1$.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.